# According to substance mind body dualism are memories formed in the brain?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

In mind body dualism, we have two fundamental substances. The mind and the body. My question is, is there any form of substance dualism where memories of ones past are formed and contained in the brain, not the immaterial mind?

Comment: Under [psychophysical parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychophysical_parallelism) you'll have all mental activities shadowed physically, in the brain presumably. So memories will be "stored" in both the mind and the brain, they'll have two aspects, one in each.

Answer (score 3):

Most substance dualists are interactionists between mind and brain. The brain does some functions, and then shares data with the mind.  Wilder Pennfield, in his direct stimulation experiments showed that detailed memories could be called up by electrical stimulation of the brain, which shows that those memories were somehow either encoded, or triggered by, that section of the brain.  Yet his experiments did not cause him to reject dualism, but rather convinced him of dualism.

Sherrington, Pennfield, Eccles, Popper, none of these dualists would deny that SOME memories are stored in the brain.